# Complex Cepstral Transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, transform, signal-processing, complex-numbers

I am trying to perform a [complex cepstral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum) on an array in MATLAB and am confused as to if `cceps(x)` is the correct command to use. Through my research I found a paper that computes the complex cepstral transform by using the formula: `c(n) = ifft(log(fft(x))`, where `x` is the audio signal. However, [`cceps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cceps.html) returns different data than this formula and the data returned by `cceps` is also not complex. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doc` for `cceps` gives literature references on the processing methods it uses. If you use `edit cceps` you can look at the code (this is the case for any toolbox functions), and you can see that `cceps` uses `ifft(log(fft(x))`, but also uses a phase unwrapping function, and does only return the real value, so in short `real(ifft(unwrap(log(fft(x)))))`. You could edit the function to return the complex value if you wanted.

Comment: Oh okay I see. So if I do edit the function and return all of the values, real and complex, will doing the inverse return me back to the original real data? For some reason when I use the full formula and the inverse of the formula I do not get back to the original data and the data is still complex.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? (probably not, but it should be close)

Comment: I did try and the returned data is still complex.

Comment: What is the imaginary component like? Does taking just the `real` part or the `abs` look like the original signal? It probably won't line up if you are changing one function and not another. Why don't you just use `ifft(log(fft(x)))` and the inverse if you are looking to reproduce a paper's method? Matlab's version is slightly different, but what difference does it make to your application?

Answer (score 0):

for me cceps(x) and c(n)=ifft(log(fft(x)) return very near results

Code example:

```
frame = signal;
win = hamming(length(frame));
windowedSignal = frame.*win;
fftResult=log(abs(fft(windowedSignal)));
ceps=ifft(fftResult);
subplot(2,1,1); plot(ceps); legend('c(n)=ifft(log(fft(x))');
subplot(2,1,2); plot(cceps(frame));legend('cceps');
```

The difference we see here seems to be caused by the windowing

[image]